# SQLite3 — сгенерированный столбец

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть у меня правило для сгенерированного столбца, вот оно:

```
number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr('0000' || id, length('id'), 4)) STORED
```

Но, когда номер доходит до десятки (0010), происходит ошибка. Если уменьшить число нолей на один, то та же ошибка случится, если число строк дойдёт до сотни (0100). Как сформулировать условие, чтобы не вызывало ограничений этого верхнего порога, ведь, число строк может превысить тысячу и более?

Comment: А что хотите получить в итоге? Как должно выглядеть минимально возможное число и как максимальное?

Comment: length('id') всегда равно 2 - количество символов в строке 'id'. Это выражение не имеет смысла

Comment: Ну мне нужно чтобы минимальное было 0001, а максимальное не нужно, т. е. оно может выглядеть как угодно, хоть 10300, пока не треснет sqlite :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так

```
number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (printf('%04d', id)) STORED
```

Если же делать через substr, то можно так

```
number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr('0000' || id, -max(4, length(id)), max(4, length(id)))) STORED
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! С утра бился над решением :)